Simple proof of Krein-Milman lemma in a Hilbert space
Would you please help me solve Problem 15 of Chapter 16 in Real Analysis, fourth edition, by Royden and Fitzpatrick, which I am self studying.

15. Use Proposition 2 to prove the Krein-Milman lemma in a Hilbert space.


Krein-Milman lemma Let $K$ be a nonempty, compact, convex subset of a locally convex topological vector space. Then $K$ has an extreme point.


Proposition 2 Let $K$ be a nonempty, closed, convex subset of a Hilbert space $H$ and $h_0$ belong to $H\sim K$. Then there is exactly one vector $h_*\in K$ that is closest to $h_0$ in the sense that
$$\lVert h_0 - h_*\rVert =\text{dist}(h_0,K) =\inf_{h\in K}\lVert h_0 - h\rVert.$$

I posted an answer that does not use Proposition 2. That answer works for a general inner product space whereas Proposition 2 takes advantage of completeness.
The authors' proof of the Krein-Milman lemma has two steps. The authors first apply Zorn's lemma to find an extreme subset $E$ of $K$ that contains no proper subset that also is an extreme subset of $K$. Second, they infer from a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem that $E$ is a singleton set. I devised a simpler second step in an inner product space, but that is not much of a simpler proof overall because I think that the idea is to avoid using Zorn's lemma (as in my posted answer).
I am trying not to think too hard because the authors write, "The proofs of many results we established for general Banach spaces are much simpler for the special case of Hilbert spaces; see Problems 11–15."
One thing that is distracting me is that $h_*$ is not necessarily an extreme point of $K$.
